# Jquery conditional selector

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with conditional selector. I have some inputfields. I want change border color of empty fields with required attribute.

What I tried:

```
$("[required='required']").css({
      "border": "1px solid #FF0000",
      "background": "#FFEFFF"
  });

  $("[required='required']").blur(function ()  {
    comp(this);
  });

$("[required='required']").keyup(function ()  {
    comp(this);
  });

$("[required='required']").click(function ()  {
    comp(this);
  });

  function comp(a) {
      if ($(a).val() !== "")
          $(a).css({
          "border": "1px solid #ccc",
          "background": ""
      });

      else $(a).css({
          "border": "1px solid #FF0000",
          "background": "#FFEFFF"
      });

  }
```

Here is a link to: http://jsfiddle.net/guwanchat/HjzVu/14/

Comment: Can you please also post your code here?

Comment: You want to change the color after submit or on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you don't initialize your elements according to the `comp` function.

I modified your starting code from this:

```
$("[required='required']").css({
      "border": "1px solid #FF0000",
      "background": "#FFEFFF"
});
```

to this:

```
$("[required='required']").each(function () {
    comp(this);
});
```

I use the jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to iterate the objects that match the selector and call the comp function to initialize them.

### jQuery.each()

> Description: A generic iterator function, which can be used to
>   seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like
>   objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object)
>   are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are
>   iterated via their named properties.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HjzVu/19/