# Set style to required fields in jsf with jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269091/jquery-conditional-selector) question before: But I need use it in jsf. I use primefaces library in my application. My code is here:

```
Jsf: <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />           
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $ = jQuery;  $(document).ready(function() {
         $("p:inpuText").each(function () {
        comp(this);
    });

   $("[required='true']").blur(function ()  {
        comp(this);
      });

   $("[required='true']").keyup(function ()  {
      comp(this);
       });


   $("[required='true']").click(function ()  {
        comp(this);
      });



      function comp(a) {
          if ($(a).val() != "")
              $(a).css({
              "border": "1px solid #ccc !important",
              "background": "#FFF"
          });

          else $(a).css({
              "border": "1px solid #FF0000 !important",
              "background": "#FFEFFF"
          });



      }
```

});

I want set css to empty required fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a conceptual thinking mistake. JS/jQuery doesn't run on JSF code. Instead, it runs on JSF-produced HTML code. Open JSF page in browser, rightclick, *View Source*. Do you see it? It's one and all HTML code. There are no `<p:inputText>` elements in there, just `<input>` elements. No one `<input>` element has `required="true"` set either.

Give them e.g. a specific style class instead:

```
<p:inputText ... required="true" styleClass="required" />
```

So that it generates the following HTML:

```
<input ... class="required" />
```

So that you can select them in jQuery by e.g.:

```
$(":input.required")
```

A custom renderer or tag file should remove the need to write down the style class everytime.

Comment: Dear BalusC. Your answer work only for inputText fields. But not working with some primefaces components like p:calendar or p:selectOneMenu. Can you test my code with your solution. Thank you.